# Float PPM image file format?

Tags: image, image-processing, file-format, ppm, hdrimages

I've found a PPM image with the header starting with **PF** (instead of standard P6, P5, P4, ... signatures).
The resolution number is stored in floating point (**-1.000**).
No comments are inserted to get how it was produced.

Because the resolution, I derived that each pixel is composed by 12 bytes (4 bytes per component)... I suppose they are float or integer numbers.

*The problem is that I cannot get a clear image. Someone has already found this kind of images?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Portable Float Map [HDR Shop description](http://gl.ict.usc.edu/HDRShop/PFM/PFM_Image_File_Format.html).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, having a look at the open source [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) might help you. As it has wrappers for different languages, this looks like a worthwhile shot at this, as you have not stated the programming language specifics, I thought this may be the neutral solution for you...